# Asynchronously display data with react-leaflet's GeoJSON

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I have no trouble rendering geojson data by returning this in my render function :

```
<Map ref={(ref) => { this.map = ref; }} center={position} zoom={13}>
    <TileLayer
        attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
    <GeoJSON data={this.state.geojson_data} /> }
</Map>
```

so next thing I tried is initializing *this.state.geojson_data* with null, and then loading data on *componentDidMount*, then I modified the line with the GeoJSON to this one, because obvisouly, null is not a valid geojson object.

```
 { this.state.geojson_data !== null && <GeoJSON data={this.state.geojson_data} /> }
```

data is fetched with no problem, but my geojson doesnt show at all, anybody knows why ?

I can see two ways of circumventing that :

1. using the map reference to add the layer the vanilla leaflet way, but I'd like to use a more react approach.
2. loading the data with the parent component and giving it as a prop, but I like the idea that the map is initializing and loading while the data loads, rather than after the data loads.

EDIT1: I investigated a little further and tried to feed the GeoJSON component some non geojson data, and it made an error, it still didn't draw the layer when the data is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a referential problem, I'm sorry I cant explain further, the gis people I talked with gave me another version of this geojson with another referential, it worked as intended.

the error is on me though, I first tried with a hardcoded geojson, and I was sure my backend used this same data when I tried loading it and it was the other one with the wrong referential.

EDIT: the people handling our gis gave us a geojson that didnt used the right referential